# Show post thumbnail linstead of place holder

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add the post thumbnail to the span but I am not to sure how to do that what is my best way to achieve the following i tried

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="single_service_item">
                            <div class="service_icon transition3s">
                                <div class="icon_border">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                                    <span  style=" background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/chrome_2017-11-09_10-46-33.png");"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="service_text">
                                <h5><?php the_title();?></h5>
                                <p><?php the_content();?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

But the following is the style of it 
[image]

You can see the site here http://ubtanz.solitudesoftware.co.uk/ its the circle image i want to replace with the image of the post thumbnail

Comment: You have a problem with margin in the icon_border class.

Comment: @VisualBean thanks i got it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) to get post thumbnail url.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="single_service_item">
            <div class="service_icon transition3s">
                <div class="icon_border">
                    <span style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full'); ?>');"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="service_text">
                <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```